# location of current browser page on pc

Tags: internet-explorer, explorer

Where on my pc can I find the Internet Explorer page I am currently looking at in the browser.
I want to write a program to extract information from it

It must be there somewhere but I can't find it in Temporary Internet Files

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to do what I clearly said. Read the file on my pc that is the page I am viewing in the browser to extract information USING A PROGRAM. In an automated way. It can be done manually but is long-winded and time-consuming and impractical

Comment: I was trying to figure out what you were doing so I could suggest a better solution. But I will let you be.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it looks like you want to scrape the information from a webpage using IE Automation.

Site data gets stored in the Temporary Internet Files, If you are seeing many files there and you are not able to find the files for the site you are seeing in the IE at present then you can try to sort and group files by right click the mouse button and select the desired option for sort by and group by.

I think that you do not need to find a file/webpage like this. If your goal is to check the source code of the webpage then you can press the **F12 key** in the IE window will launch the developer tools. Here, you can easily check the source code of the webpage, and based on that you can write a program to extract the information from it.

[image]

If you still want to access the page on your machine then you can simply go to `File-> Save As` or press the `CTRL + S` key in the IE window to save the webpage locally. then you can easily access it from the saved location.

Let us know if I misunderstand anything or if you have any further questions regarding this issue, I will try to provide further suggestions.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Not answering my question

Comment: I obviously know all that already.
I am trying to find the file I am currently viewing and it doesn't seem to be in the temporary folder

Comment: It looks like we need more information about your logic for extracting the information from the webpage. Based on my understanding, You do not need to access the web page from Temporary Internet Files. If you can provide more information then I can try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: You somehow manage not to understand what is so very simple.
I am looking at a page in the browser. I want to access that page via a program. As I can see it, it must BE on my pc.
I've looked in the Temporary Internet Files directory and it isn't there. the resources are but not the page.
So where IS it?
I know what I can do manually thank you but I need an automated process

Comment: If the webpage you are seeing in the browser is publicly available then you can try to share the link to that page. We can try to visit the page and try to check and find it on the machine.

Comment: We need information for reproducing the issue on our end to find the cause of the issue and for providing possible suggestions for the issue. At present, we do not know what site you are seeing in the browser and the issue cannot be produced using any random site. Without checking that information, nobody will be able to tell why you are not able to find that page on a machine. Your explanation about your automation process is also not clear. without clear information, it will be hard to provide any further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.